# Why do I see extra text at the top of my view page when using the @Model statement?

Tags: vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

VS2013, MVC5, VB, MVC MusicStore practice

I have a View that successfully displays the results of an album search using ViewData.  The code for the Controller is shown below. 'q' is the search data passed in from the Search Page link.

```
Function SandboxSearchResults(q As String) As ActionResult
  Dim albumQuery As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of MvcMusicStore.Album)
  albumQuery = db.Albums.Include("Artist").Where(Function(x) x.Title.Contains(q)).Take(10)
  ViewData("albumList") = albumQuery
  Return View()
End Function
```

And the View is:

```
@Code
  ViewData("Title") = "SandboxSearchResults"
End Code

<h2>SandboxSearchResults</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Artist</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
@For Each A As Album In ViewData("albumList")
  @<tr>
     <td>@A.Artist.ArtistName</td>
     <td>@A.Title</td>
     <td>@A.Price</td>
   </tr>
Next
</table>
```

If I simply add the following statement to the start of the View before the @Code statement:

```
@Model IEnumerable[MvcMusicStore.Models.Album]
```

Then the following line shows up at the top of my View

```
IEnumerable[MvcMusicStore.Models.Album]
```

If I only change my View call to View(albumQuery) I get even more at the top of my View as below:

```
SELECT [Limit1].[AlbumId] AS [AlbumId], [Limit1].[GenreId] AS [GenreId], [Limit1].[ArtistID] AS [ArtistID], [Limit1].[Title] AS [Title], [Limit1].[Price] AS [Price], [Limit1].[AlbumArtURL] AS [AlbumArtURL], [Limit1].[ArtistID1] AS [ArtistID1], [Limit1].[ArtistName] AS [ArtistName] FROM ( SELECT TOP (10) [Extent1].[AlbumId] AS [AlbumId], [Extent1].[GenreId] AS [GenreId], [Extent1].[ArtistID] AS [ArtistID], [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], [Extent1].[Price] AS [Price], [Extent1].[AlbumArtURL] AS [AlbumArtURL], [Extent2].[ArtistID] AS [ArtistID1], [Extent2].[ArtistName] AS [ArtistName] FROM [dbo].[Albums] AS [Extent1] INNER JOIN [dbo].[Artists] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ArtistID] = [Extent2].[ArtistID] WHERE [Extent1].[Title] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~' ) AS [Limit1] IEnumerable[MvcMusicStore.Models.Album]
```

My reason for passing the model in was to see alternate ways to get data to the View.

Where is this coming from and why is it being displayed?  What do I do to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be referencing @Model type by specifying the actual type like so:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of MvcMusicStore.Models.Album)
```

[Documented here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/vb/accessing-your-model's-data-from-a-controller).

Comment: Thanks for the link!  It did explain.  For those who may read this later we should clear something up.  I used the line of code above first, and Intellisense immediately complained.  So I followed your link and it indicated the following: @ModelType IEnumerable(of MvcMusicStore.Album).  That latter syntax using the (of T) worked properly.